# Qt Link Issue with MyClass::metaobject VS2005

Tags: c++, qt, linker, meta, moc

Just quickly before I start, I have searched SO and Google for a length of time trying to solve this and have been unsuccessful.

I am trying to compile my project, which used to use a certain library for providing GUI functionality based on Windows Forms. Now my company has started to move to Qt, and I decided I would start to convert my small application to support Qt also.

At first it would not compile at all, due to missing headers. Now that is sorted, I am stuck with my final .exe not being able to link due to the following errors.

```
Creating library Bin\VS_V8\Win32\Debug\Disp.lib and object Bin\VS_V8\Win32\Debug\Disp.exp
QtMainMenu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QtMainMenu::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QtMainMenu@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
QtMainMenu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall QtMainMenu::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QtMainMenu@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
QtMainMenu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall QtMainMenu::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QtMainMenu@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
Bin\VS_V8\Win32\Debug\Disp.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Our company has a small "Qt Test App" that was written to play around with, which is where I have based my import from. I can compile and link that fine. From what I have gathered, the following properties must be met with Qt files:

- Make sure QTDir is included
- Add to the UI Files the UIC Compiler
- Add to the Resoruce Files the Resource Compiler
- Add to the created Header Files the MOC compiler.

I noticed I was missing the MOC Build Tool commands, so I have added them to my UI File's header. However this didnt change the linking problem. I read that I should delete all built files and do a clean to solve it. This didnt work either.

I have checked, and Q_OBJECT is defined in the class.

I am using VS2005 with the Qt Addin. I did not start a new project for Qt however, I am just using the old Visual Studio Solution / VCProj.

Any ideas where to go next?

Comment: It *sounds* like you might be missing the linking of the source file created by the MOC compiler. Normally that would be taken care of automatically by using `qmake`, but it sounds like you're doing things with your own VS build file. In that case, you'll have to make sure you do all the steps that `qmake` would normally do.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I will have a quick look into that now and come back to you :)

Comment: @GregHewgill I think I can confirm linking in the MOC. Just noticed after generating the moc_class.cpp that my include for the header has become #include "../../Lib/Include/QtForms/QtMainMenu.h" and this cpp class contains the missing functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cameron Stubber you need `moc` object .. You need to modify Custom Build Step.

You can find `Custom Build Step` in header file (which has Q_OBJECT) `Properties` by right click. Then type this commands ;

```
Command Line = $(QTDIR)\bin\moc.exe -I"$(QTDIR)\include\QtCore" -I"$(QTDIR)\include\QtGui" -I"$(QTDIR)\include" -I"$(QTDIR)\mkspecs\$(QMAKESPEC)" finddialog.h -o debug\moc_finddialog.cpp

Description = MOC finddialog.h

Outputs = debug\moc_finddialog.cpp

Additional Dependencies = $(QTDIR)\bin\moc.exe;finddialog.h
```

But carefull by writing this types you need to change somethings here like `$(QTDIR)` it is my enviroment variables you need to write full form of where your QT located like `D:\qt_5\`

and also you need to be carefull `finddialog` you should write your `.h and .cpp` files name

And then you need to create a folder by right clicking solution explorer `Add\New Filter` .. Make folder name as `Generated Files`

And last step right click `Generated Files`  add\existing item  and you will see Debug folder in your solution Project and add `moc_"projectName".cpp`

Then re-build your solution. Problem will be solved.

Also you should add C/C++ /General/Additional Library Directories

```
$(QTDIR)\include
$(QTDIR)\include\QtGui
$(QTDIR)\include\QtCore
```

And Link/General/Additional Library Directories

```
$(QTDIR)\lib
```

Link/Input/Additional Dependencies

```
qtmaind.lib
QtCored4.lib
QtGuid4.lib
```

But dont forget to change `$(QTDIR)` to your `enviroment variables` or location of your qt folder. Like `D:\qt_4.7.4`

Comment: <img src="http://i.imgur.com/T8ypXdF.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/WFDAfnK.png">

Guess the mini-Markdown guide for images is a liar... Sorry :)

Comment: Did you modified your header file's Custom Build Step which has Q_OBJECT ? If you did, make sure that you write variables correctly .. And do not forget to add moc_ProjectName.cpp file in your Project.

Comment: Change **$(InputPath)** to **QtMainMenu.h** and make sure your Command Line is correct.

Comment: and Also i noticed that you are using **$(QTDIR)** . Are you using **$(QTDIR)** enviroment variables ? My advice is to change **$(QTDIR)** to your **Qt location** like **D:\qt_4.7.4\** or where your file is located.

Comment: Did that, still the same.

Comment: Can I ask, Should the QtMainMenu.cpp include the moc_QtMainMenu.cpp? It looks like the 3 unresolved external functions are inside the moc file, but they are not being included in making the .obj

Comment: Can you close visual studio and open again.

Comment: Does nothing. I just added "#include "moc_QtMainMenu.cpp" into my QtMainMenu.cpp and it linked fine. However now I just have a White Screen when there should be just some basic buttons. Thanks for the help so far team!

Comment: Solved - forgot to do application.exec();

Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, now I just need to get my head around recompiling the Ui with new components on it and repeating.